# Libevent - Running the loop(event_base_loop)

Tags: c, libevent

Tell me please, here is a quote from reference section 3 ("[Running an event loop](http://www.wangafu.net/%7Enickm/libevent-book/Ref3_eventloop.html)") of Nick Mathewson's [book on Libevent](http://www.wangafu.net/%7Enickm/libevent-book/):

> By default, the event_base_loop() function runs an event_base until
> there are no more events registered in it.

Honestly, I just can't understand this phrase.

What means - "until there are no more events registered".

How does a loop know that there are no more new events ?? There can be a time interval between events - 1 second, 1 hour ...

How does Libevent know that events are over?

PS: I'm trying to compare the work of the event_base_loop () function with the GetQueuedCompletionStatus () function on windows and I don't get it. Because GetQueuedCompletionStatus works in an infinite loop - whether there are events or not - GetQueuedCompletionStatus waits for an infinitely new event and does not complete if there are none.

PS1:I was in a hurry and did not finish the chapter on "Working with an event loop".

It says that you can redefine the behavior of the event_base_loop () function by passing it a flag in the second parameter - EVLOOP_NO_EXIT_ON_EMPTY.

This will mean that the function will wait for new events indefinitely or until I want to exit the event_base_loop () loop manually via event_base_loopbreak / event_base_loopexit.

Comment: Read it like "... until there are no more *current* events..."

Comment: The [current wording](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-2.1/doxygen/html/event_8h.html#a76e311cff042dab77125e309315a0617) appears to be "By default, this loop will run the event base until either there are no more pending or active events, or until something calls event_base_loopbreak() or event_base_loopexit(). You can override this behavior with the 'flags' argument."

Comment: @Some programmer dude, But after all, when I start the event_base_loop, there may not be events yet. And even if there is - then when all the Current events end - after them, for example, after 1 minute, other events may appear? I just can't figure it out :(

Comment: Re "*when I start the event_base_loop, there may not be events yet.*", No events means no pending or active events, so the docs indicate it would just return then.

Comment: @ikegami, I'm trying to compare the work of the event_base_loop () function with the GetQueuedCompletionStatus () function on windows and I don't get it. Because GetQueuedCompletionStatus works in an infinite loop - whether there are events or not - GetQueuedCompletionStatus waits for an infinitely new event and does not complete if there are none.

Answer (score 2):

Note it says "no more events *registered*", rather than "no more *events*". By default, the event loop will exit when the event base runs empty, even though more events *could* happen later. This is restated in a different way both later in the chapter:

> Ordinarily, the loop will exit as soon as it has no pending or active events.

and in the API documentation for [`event_base_loop()`](http://www.wangafu.net/%7Enickm/libevent-2.1/doxygen/html/event_8h.html#a76e311cff042dab77125e309315a0617):

> By default, this loop will run the event base until either there are no more pending or active events, or until something calls event_base_loopbreak() or event_base_loopexit().

As noted in the question, `EVLOOP_NO_EXIT_ON_EMPTY` can change this behavior to work more like a typical event queue, waiting for events (unless `EVLOOP_NONBLOCK` was set) and dispatching them when they arrive.

"[Running an event loop](http://www.wangafu.net/%7Enickm/libevent-book/Ref3_eventloop.html)" contains pseudocode for `event_base_loop()` that should also help clarify the behavior.

In comparison, `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` will wait for and operate on a single packet (note: the wait is not likely a busyloop but based on some other multitasking technologies, such as interrupts and thread synchronization primitives; the exact method is an implementation detail, and shouldn't affect use). It's most similar to `event_base_loop()` with the flags `EVLOOP_ONCE | EVLOOP_NO_EXIT_ON_EMPTY`, though `event_base_loop` may process multiple events of the same priority if they happen to come in before the first event is fully handled. Coming from the other direction, if 0 is passed for the `dwMilliseconds` argument to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`, it behaves like `event_base_loop()`'s default behavior, exiting immediately if there are no packets in the I/O completion queue.

Comment: This is a good explanation.  Perhaps the main source of confusion is the OP seems to think Libevent "event_base_loop()" (or, similarly, "event_base_dispatch()") behaves just like Win32 GetQueuedCompletionStatus().